# GlobalGraphOperations results in NullPointerException not in Transaction, but why?

Tags: java, neo4j

Here is my little Snippet which is throwing a NullPointerException.

```
public class HelloJavaApi {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphDatabaseService db = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data");
    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
      GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllLabels();
      tx.success();
    }
  }
}
```

AssertInTransaction throws it because `ThreadToStatementContextBridge` in `GlobalGraphOperations` is null. There seems to be a problem in the constructor of `GlobalGraphOperations` because the resolver is not null, but the resolver doesn't work all it returns is null. What to do?

I'm using Java 7 and neo4j 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that. There is a operation on RestGraphDatabase for getting all labels `getAllLabelNames()`.

It is not a full GraphDatabase implementation that can be passed to utilities that cast it use it internally with other SPIs

Comment: Ok, if we cant use `GlobalGraphOperations` with `RestGraphDatabase` (which is in itself not very nice) , what about the other useful methods that exist there, like `getAllNodesWithLabel` ? 

Also, what is the correct way to connect to a neo4j remote server without using `RestGraphDatabase` and end up with a fully functional `GraphDatabaseService`  ? 

I probably jumped over that part of the documentation.